# Press on arrow keys without focusing on any control

Tags: c#, navigation, arrow-keys

I have a windows form that has bunch of controls.  Whenever any key is clicked, like arrow keys, I want to raise an event.  The problem isn't in code, the problem is that the controls have a tab index so anytime I click on arrow keys the cursor just moves to another control and that's what I don't want.

Comment: capture the event in the form itself and set KeyPreview to false.

Comment: @HighCore - must be set to true, by default it is false

Comment: @AppDeveloper That's what I meant. I have not used dinosaur winforms in a loong while.

Comment: @HighCore -  he he happens!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14530877/922198

Comment: @R.Vector - ans updated,do check it for sure!

Comment: Thanks everybody for the great help, i fixed it because of your suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure that there isn't any active control on the current form. Put this code in Form.cs

```
this.ActiveControl = null;
```

Comment: That piece of code solved the whole issue, of course i had to add this.KeyPreview = true;

Comment: I had the same problem a year ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Attach each controls KeyDown event to the same handler:

```
 Control.KeyDown+=new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown);

 private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        //trap here and handle
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            e.Handled = true;
 }
```

Comment: this will completely seize the function of Arrow Keys, imagine you are one a TextBox control and the Arrow are not working to change cursor position within TextBox

Comment: Agreed, there would need to be a procedure that tested for an edit control and handle accordingly…

Answer (score 2):

After some testing i found out

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

This will cause the arrow keys (and tab) to be delivered as normal KeyDown events. This will also cause the normal dialogue key functionality (For e.g. Tab & Arrow keys) to stop, but still get the KeyDown event